# How to insert integer value in access database?

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2007

I am trying to insert Integer value into MS-Access database by using datagridview, but other string values are entered successfully but integer is not. I use debugger also but when debugger come to that line its showing me null value. In my database I use Memo as datatype for Availability, here is my code and possible snapshot

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
            {
                string connectionString = null;
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                string cmd1 = "insert into Medicine_Available_Detail(Medicine_Name,Dealer_name,Availability) values(?,?,@Availability)";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                string Medicine_Name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", Medicine_Name);

                string Dealer_name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dealer_name"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dealer_name", Dealer_name);

 string Availability = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Availability"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", Availability);


                con.Open();
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (n > 0)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully", "Data Inserted ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


                }

            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            Load_data();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();

           }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: OleDB does not support named parameters as such.  You need to add the parameters in the exact same order that they appear in the SQL

Comment: @plutonix : i added same way only